# Diffusion on infinite line with no flux

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving the diffusion equation $$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial x^2} $$ on an infinite line with initial condition that the particle density $\rho(t=0.1,x)$ is a normal distribution. For a no flux boundary condition I get an error in Matlab. Is it not possible to have no flux in this case as there are "no ends to insulate"?

Comment: Not sure about general Gaussian distributions, but for some specific $\rho(0.1,x)$, namely, $$\rho(0.1,x)=A \exp\left(-2.5\frac{x^2}{D}\right)\,,$$ with the boundary conditions $\rho(t,\pm\infty)=0$, you will end up with Gaussian distributions at all times $t$, i.e. $$\rho(x,t)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{t}}\,\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right)\,.$$  See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55629/solving-the-diffusion-equation.  I doubt that there exists a nice analytic solution for other $\rho(0.1,x)$, even if it is Gaussian.

Comment: How exactly you are trying to use Matlab to solve a problem on an infinite interval?